# Json boolean column - display in html as yes, no, or undefined if it's missing

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a boolean json attribute in a database table.  During a conversion, some of the attributes were missed and didn't get added to some of the records.  Using the code below, undefined ones display as 'No' - which is misleading.  Is there an ez way to display it as 'undefined' in this example?

```
 <div *ngSwitchCase="'boolean'">
                <ng-container *ngIf="rowAttribute.visible===true" matColumnDef={{rowAttribute.header}}>
                  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header (click)="sort(rowAttribute.name, false, 'number')"> {{rowAttribute.header}} </th>
                  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element[rowAttribute.name] ? 'Yes' : 'No'}} </td>
                </ng-container>
              </div>
```

Comment: Wouldn't changing the `No` to `undefined` in `{{element[rowAttribute.name] ? 'Yes' : 'No'}} ` work just fine?

Comment: It would, but in this case I'm trying to query on the actual value and since it doesn't exist - I have to write a workaround for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 {{element[rowAttribute.name] === true ? 'Yes' : element[rowAttribute.name] === false ? 'No' : 'Missing'}}
```

More detailed notes: When you use the ternary operator (`a ? b : c`) it converts `a` to a boolean. Both `false` and `undefined` are converted to `false`. You'll need to do something more specific than the default JavaScript falsy check if you want to treat `false` as different than `undefined`. Consider this:

```js
const inputs = [undefined, true, false, null, '', 1, 0];

inputs.map(input => {
  const asBoolean = !!input;
  const isTrue = input === true;
  const isFalse = input === false;
  const isUndefined = input === undefined;
  const yourOutput = input === true ? 'Yes' : input === false ? 'No' : 'Missing';
  console.log({ input, asBoolean, isTrue, isFalse, isUndefined, yourOutput })
});
```

Comment: Helpful, yes I did read up on all of that and I'm trying to avoid this whole big thing for now, while I fix the records manually.  I tried your first solution and I thought you nailed it, but after reading the detailed notes - agree, that's not going to work.  It doesn't show 'Missing' - good answer though, thank you